# How to reproduce BOM conversion error

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, utf

I have a web app that is receiving POST data that throws the error:

`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

I'm assuming this is being caused by a BOM in the data.

I've been unable to reproduce the error in tests.  Is there a way to craft a string to cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

A stand alone programm to reproduce the error:

```
#encoding: ascii
string = "\xEFTest"

puts string.encoding
puts string.encode('utf-8')
```

If you need it inside a programm you may use `force_encoding to get a similar result:

```
string = "\xEFTest"

puts string.encoding
string.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
puts string.encode('utf-8')
```

Result:

```
test.rb:5:in `encode': "\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
  from test.rb:5:in `<main>'
UTF-8
```